Young fantasy book about a group of teenagers who have magical beasts
A young African girl in a village who is supposed to be married. She bonds with a magical beast.
On the other side of the world, a young teenage boy bonds with, I believe, a hawk or bird of some kind.
I believe there was also a bear. They had a destiny to save the world.

In roughly which year did you read this? And do you recall anything about the cover?

Could this be Wild Born by Brandon Mull?

Four children separated by vast distances all undergo the same ritual, watched by cloaked strangers. Four flashes of light erupt, and from them emerge the unmistakable shapes of incredible beasts - a wolf, a leopard, a panda, a falcon. Suddenly the paths of these children - and the world - have been changed for ever. Enter the world of Erdas, where every child who comes of age must discover if they have a spirit animal, a rare bond between human and beast that bestows great powers to both. A dark force has risen from distant and long-forgotten lands, and has begun an onslaught that will ravage the world. Now the fate of Erdas has fallen on the shoulders of four young strangers ...and on you.


